# How do I post from a RoR app to LinkedIn group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

How do I use LinkedIn API, OmniAuth-LinkedIn and LinkedIn gem post feeds to my LinkedIn Group?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the LinkedIn APIs, then you simply need to make a post call like so:

```
POST http://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/{group-id}/posts
```

and pass in your group discussion input:

```
<post>
  <title>New Group Discussion</title>
  <summary>What does everyone think about platform development?</summary>
  <content>
    <submitted-url>http://developer.linkedin.com</submitted-url>
    <title>Build the Professional Web with LinkedIn</title>
    <description>A great resource for finding documentation and answers related to developing on the LinkedIn Platform</description>
  </content>
</post>
```

You can get more details here: https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/sharing-content-your-group-discussion-posts

Comment: have you used any Ruby gem (wrapper). I am still confused whether I can use the LinkedIn gem to authenticate and post to my group... Thanks for the reply. It's very helpful.

Comment: Check out the Ruby OAuth gem (http://oauth.rubyforge.org). Making authenticated calls with this gem is very easy. You can reference this doc as there are examples on how to authenticate in Ruby using the OAuth gem: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

Comment: Yes I just discovered that, but I never done it. Thanks for extra tip. Ideally I'd like to allow users to connect to my app via LinkedIn. I guess I need to experiment and learn to use the API and the gems. Cheers.